# hbase client upgrade from 94.x to 96.x

Tags: java, hbase

I'm trying to connect with HBase via. Java program . we have version upgrade from 94.x to 96.x sothe java client need to upgrade as well . Legacy code was using "hbase-0.94.17" and it has been change to use "hbase-client-0.96.1.1-hadoop2" jar file however after this change , class "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;" is not present in class path and I'm getting compile time error. Please advice if any other jar need to add in class path .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switching the jar may not be enough. You have to recompile against the new jars (some api may be changed or at least deprecated, so you should check)

anyway, there are now two jars hbase-client and hbase-common that you have to include. HBaseConfiguration is in hbase-common